# CopyFilesToOutputDirectory log relative path

Tags: msbuild

I have big log file for logging compile output from MSBuild and I am looking for a way how can I clean this file by logging only relative path from absolute path.

For now I have logging like this one:

```
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
         Copying file from "E:\Data\Jenkins\workspace\develop_BUILD_CH\ux1\fol1\fol2\obj\Release\xyz.pdb" to "E:\Data\Jenkins\workspace\develop_BUILD_CH\out\Release\xyz.pdb".
```

and I want to get something like this:

```
ux1\fol1\fol2\obj\Release\xyz.pdb
```

Comment: For manual investigations? If so i'd suggest to use [binary logs](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/master/documentation/wiki/Binary-Log.md) with the [structured log viewer](https://msbuildlog.com/)

Comment: I didn't know about it, I will try this. Thank you.